# I can't get a div next to three divs that are centered

Tags: html, css, p5.js

I'm trying to place a div that contains `p5.js` script to the left of 3 divs that are centered.

Here is my HTML for the specific section:

```
 <div class = "container">
        <div class = "canvasLeft">
            <script src = "sketch2.js"></script>
        </div>

        <div class = "logo">
            <img src = "Img/BarberLogo.png" width = "300px" />
        </div>

        <div class = "comics">
            <a href = "C:/MRT page/Barber Sauce Comics.pdf">comics</a>
        </div>

        <div class = "frontCover">
            <a href = "C:/MRT page/Barber Sauce Comics.pdf">
                <img src = "Img/FrontCover1.png"/ width = "200px"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}

.canvasLeft{
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.comics{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.frontCover{
    text-align:center;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of flex methods and positioning methods but none of them seem to work.

[example of how the divs should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3sRB.png)

Comment: Can you create a image in paint, how do you want the structure to be?

Comment: can you post a picture of your desired layout?

Comment: I find it strange you are putting a script tag inside a div. Also, you are inconsistent with using closing slashes on `<img>` tags but the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: I placed the script tag in the div thinking it would add the canvas to that div, however when using ```p5.js``` it automatically creates a canvas at the bottom of the screen. I found a way around this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you are trying to do. If I am envisioning your desired layout correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/wjcz3k6x/

I put the centered divs in their own wrapper and left the canvas out of it. Then used display flex on the container to have them sit side by side. You can adjust the widths as needed for your own taste.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.canvasLeft{
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 40%;
}

.content-wrapper {
  flex: 60%;
  background: red;
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.comics{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.frontCover{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class = "container">
   <div class = "canvasLeft">
     <script src = "sketch2.js"></script>
   </div>

   <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class = "logo">
            <img src = "Img/BarberLogo.png" width = "300px" />
        </div>

        <div class = "comics">
            <a href = "C:/MRT page/Barber Sauce Comics.pdf">comics</a>
        </div>

        <div class = "frontCover">
            <a href = "C:/MRT page/Barber Sauce Comics.pdf">
                <img src = "Img/FrontCover1.png"/ width = "200px">
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This put the div where I wanted it, but for some reason the canvas is being created at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: its okay I figured it out.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you set `position: absolute;` for div with class `.canvasLeft` but its parent isn't relative...set `position: relative;` for div with class `.container`,also set width and height `.canvasLeft` to 100%,"inherit" doesn't work in `position: absolute;`